# Is there a way to open menu item in MenuStrip as a tab?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, menustrip

I'm trying to make a simple translator but I have a problem with menustrip. I created 3 items such as: Translate, About, Exit. What I tried to do but fail is that when I click "About", I want it to be opened as a new tab and there will be an image about the language. When I click "Translate", it will go back to the main page where you write a text and click the button to translate it. Lastly, when you click the "Exit" one, program will close itself.

I did the "Exit" one by writing:

```
private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

I already found a way to open "About" page in a new form when you click it but I want them all to be in the same form but in different tabs. How can I do it?

Comment: This would be too easy if you actually had a tabbed UI.  So you probably don't.  Consider doing this the way that every program does it, show About help in a dialog.  Very easy to do with MessageBox or a dedicated form, call ShowDialog().

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show "tabs" in a form, you can try the control "TabControl". Then you can refer to the following code to use it.

```
private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create new tab
    TabPage tp = new TabPage("Test");
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);
    // Add control into the tab
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    tb.Multiline = true;
    tp.Controls.Add(tb);
    this.tabControl1.SelectedTab = this.tabControl1.TabPages[1];
}
```